# Python: how to Parse and check the time?

Tags: python, regex, parsing, time

How do I extract the IP address that occurs 10 times within a one-second time interval?

In the following case:

> 241.7118.197.10
>
> 28.252.8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could collect the data to `dict` where IP is key and value contains timestamps for given IP. Then every time when timestamp is added you could check if given IP has three timestamps within a second:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from collections import defaultdict, deque
import re

THRESHOLD = timedelta(seconds=1)
COUNT = 3

res = set()
d = defaultdict(deque)

with open('test.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # Capture IP and timestamp
        m = re.match(r'(\S*)[^\[]*\[(\S*)', line)
        ip, dt = m.groups()

        # Parse timestamp
        dt = datetime.strptime(dt, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%f')

        # Remove timestamps from deque if they are older than threshold
        que = d[ip]
        while que and (dt - que[0]) > THRESHOLD:
            que.popleft()

        # Add timestamp, update result if there's 3 or more items
        que.append(dt)
        if len(que) >= COUNT:
            res.add(ip)

print(res)
```

Result:

```
{'28.252.89.140'}
```

Above reads the logfile containing the log line by line. For every line a regular expression is used to capture data in two groups: IP and timestamp. Then [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) is used to parse the time.

First group `(\S*)` captures everything but whitespace. Then `[^\[]*` captures everything except `[` and `\[` captures the final character before timestamp. Finally `(\S*)` is used again to capture everything until next whitespace. See [example on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/ytmSWn/5).

Once we have IP and time they are added to [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) where IP is used as key and value is [`deque`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/collections.html#collections.deque) of timestamps. Before new timestamp is added the old ones are removed if they are older than `THRESHOLD`. This assumes that log lines are already sorted by time. After the addition the length is checked and if there are `COUNT` or more items in the queue IP is added to result set.

Comment: so each `dic[ ip_addr]` contains a queue?

Comment: Yes, `deque` of timestamps from where oldest items might be removed every time new timestamp is added.

Comment: is it possible to explain about the `r'(^[^\s]*)[^\[]*\[([^\s\]]*):(\d+)'`

Comment: @Maria Added explanation and link to regex101.

Comment: @niemmi Nice solution. I would add a variable with the number of occurs as a constant in the way you did with `THRESHOLD`.

Comment: @Fomalhaut Thanks for the suggestion, updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

First step would be to parse data, you can do so with this:

```
data = [(ip, datetime.strptime(time, '%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S:%f')) for (ip, time) in re.findall("((?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}).+?\[(.+?) -", text)]
```

where `text` is the input text.

This will return a list with a tuple for every entry. First element of tuple will be the ip address, second the date.

Next step is to see which ones happen in a 1 sec interval and have the same ip:

```
print set([a[0] for a in data for b in data for c in data if (datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)<a[1]-b[1]<datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)) and (datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)<a[1]-c[1]<datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)) and (datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)<b[1]-c[1]<datetime.timedelta(seconds=1))])
```

**Output:**

```
set(['28.252.89.140'])
```

Comment: Which file? You only specified that input text. If that text is in a file, you should first read it.

Comment: Using this two lines you will need two modules: `re` and `datetime`